# iOS - Need to have only 4 tabs shown in my app

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

In my Tab bar based iOS application, i've 8 tabs. So in main screens 4 tabs are shown and 5th one is "more" tab.
Is it possible to show only 3 tabs + 1 more tab in my application main screen?
When user clicks, let it show the remaining options as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not possible using the standard `UITabBarController`. You will have to create a custom variant to get this accomplished.